# Linq to xml - search XMLdocument by ID and read element next to it

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-xml

I started to learn LINQ and I need to search an XML document  for a specific ID. When I find that ID, I need to read string value of the element next to it - same level (see the structure of the attached XML).

I already created this code, using XElement and LINQ to XML it works but I have feeling that it is not the most efficient way and would like to hear some feedback how to improve it.

E.g. when I have Field_ID 84 I want to return "Field Name second"

LINQ query:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://myapp.com/";
XElement xe = XElement.Load(filePathToLoad);

var xeQueryXmlOneOnly = from xItem in xe.Descendants(ns + "Item")
            where xItem.Element(ns + "Field_ID").Value.Equals("84")
            select new
            {
                fieldName = xItem.Elements(ns + "Field_Name").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                fieldID = xItem.Elements(ns + "Field_ID").FirstOrDefault().Value
            };

var resultsFound = xeQueryXmlOneOnly.FirstOrDefault();
```

Simplified XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<exns:recordCollection xmlns:exns="http://myapp.com/" xmlns:ns1="urn:my-scripts" xmlns:ns2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:ns3="urn:XsltUtils">
  <exns:record>
    <exns:Application_Name>My App</exns:Application_Name>
    <exns:Field_Information>
      <exns:Item>
        <exns:Field_ID>1184</exns:Field_ID>
        <exns:Field_Name>Field name 1</exns:Field_Name>
      </exns:Item>
      <exns:Item>
        <exns:Field_ID>84</exns:Field_ID>
        <exns:Field_Name>Field Name second</exns:Field_Name>
      </exns:Item>
      <exns:Item>
        <exns:Field_ID>8426</exns:Field_ID>
        <exns:Field_Name>Field name last</exns:Field_Name>
      </exns:Item>
    </exns:Field_Information>
  </exns:record>
</exns:recordCollection>
```

In reality the XML doc will be much longer and it will be queried in a huge loop querying huge number of IDs - so maybe here comes also related question - is there a way to get all at once (something similar to SQL WHERE ID IN (.....))?

Comment: Will the IDs be unique? And the xml be well formatted always?

Answer (score 0):

a) If performance could be an issue I would suggest use XMLReader instead of LINQ.

b) If the ids are unique you can update values in a Dictionary with Field_ID as key which will give you faster access. The dictionary can be built quickly using XML Reader.